# RXJS redux observable perform multiple api calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an array of contacts and would like to perform an API calls for each object in the contacts array. 
I have tried to loop over each item and make the call to fetchJson$, however, I realise that this approach is incorrect.

What is the correct way to do this with RXJS Redux Observables?

Also, this is pseudo code for the purpose of this question so please ignore any syntax errors.

```
export const createPost = (action$, store) => (
  action$.ofType(UPDATE_USER_CONTACTS)
    .switchMap(() => {
      const state = store.getState();
      const userToken = getUserToken(state);
       const userId = getuserId(state);
       const listOfContacts = getListUserContacts(state);

      return Observable.concat(
        // 1. show loading
        Observable.of(showSpinner()),
        // 2. set the timer
        Observable.defer(() => {

          const contacts = [
            {
              id: '123',
              name: 'Paul',
              phoneNumber: '000-000-00'
            },
            {
              id: '098',
              name: 'Sarah',
              phoneNumber: '111-111-11'
            },
          ]

          contacts.forEach((contact) => { 
            return fetchJson$('PUT', `${API_URL}/users/${userId}/user_contacts/${contact.id}`, userToken, {
              id: contact.id,
              name: contact.name,
              phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber,
            })
          }, false)
            .flatMap(() => (
              Observable.of(
                reset(),
                notification({
                  icon: 'm-timers',
                  text: '<b>Good - worked</b>.',
                }),
              )
            ))
            .catch(({ response }) => {
              const responseArray = [];
              if (response) {
                console.log(response, 'there was a response')
              }
              return Observable.of(...responseArray);
            });
        }),
        Observable.defer(() => {
          // perform another action here
        },
        // 4. hide loading
        Observable.of(hideSpinner()),
      );
    })
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for **forkJoin**:

> signature: forkJoin(...args, selector : function): Observable . 
>   When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

```
const contacts = [
    {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Paul',
        phoneNumber: '000-000-00'
    },
    {
        id: '098',
        name: 'Sarah',
        phoneNumber: '111-111-11'
    },
];
Observable.forkJoin(
    contacts.map((contact) => {
            return fetchJson$('PUT', `${API_URL}/users/${userId}/user_contacts/${contact.id}`, userToken, {
                id: contact.id,
                name: contact.name,
                phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber,
            })
        }
    )
);
```